# Spell check fails in LibreOffice Word 4.1.2.3 in Linux Mint 16 Petra

Tags: linux-mint, libreoffice

I am using LibreOffce 4.1.2.3 in Linux Mint 16 Petra.

When I try to run a spell check, no checking occurs, and I immediately get this response:

[image: spell check error]

It seems to indicate my language and location aren't set, so I have tried to ensure my language is set to Canadian English:

[image: setting language]

I've also double checked in the preferences:

[image: language preferences]

Nothing I have done has had any effect.

How do I get the spell checker to work?

Answer (score 0):

since a while the spell check is a plugin witch you have to install on you own.
http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center?getCategories=Dictionary

Answer (score 0):

This problem still exists in 2015 in Linux Mint 17.1. To remedy the situation, you will need to install `hunspell` or `myspell` modules for your preferred language. E.g.

```
sudo apt-get install myspell-en-us
```

Then after doing this, comes the KEY step.

Open LibreOffice and go to Tools → Options → Language Settings → Writing Aids and select the spell check modules appearing there and `Edit` them and change the language to your preferred language which has a spell-check module installed.

Also, set your preferred language in Tools → Options → Language Settings → Languages. Restart your libreoffice for the settings to take effect.

In both these setting you will see that the languages which have the spell-check modules installed will have a little spell-check icon besides their name, as shown in the screen-shot.

**Screen-shot for first setting**
[image]

**Screen-shot for second setting**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Other Option is you can Copy and Paste all the items in Tomboy Notes and then you can change all the spelling errors.

Comment: This isn't really helpful. The question is about LibreOffice and not asking about external tools.